# WSO2 Connect API Manager to Identity Server for key management

Tags: wso2

We want to connect WSO2 API Manager to WSO2 Identity server for application key management, so in other words we don't want to use the embedded key management that comes with API Manager, how can we achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

IS is used as Oauth provider, but if we think about key management part, we have no of operations managed by APIM, to restrict /allow token accesses.. 
So, if you want to use IS as keymanagement server, you need to install APIM key-management related features in IS and in the api-mgt.xml,you have to provide IS server URL/credentials under APIKeymanagment section.